# I don't understand initialization of pointer

Tags: pointers

```
int main ()
{
    int num_1 = 111;
    int *p = &num_1;

    int &ref1 = *p;
    int *(&ref2) = p;
    
    printf("&ref2 : %d\n", &ref2);
    printf("*ref2 : %d\n", *ref2);
    printf("ref2 : %d\n", ref2);

   return 0;
}
```

I get pointer literally points address.

So in `int &ref1 = *p;` ref1's address is equal to num_1's address, hence have the same value as num1 which is `111`.

However, what I don't understand is `ref2` part.

If `int *(&ref2)` is the value of `ref2` variable, shouldn't it have the same address of the num_1?

Comment: `int *(&ref2)` is not a _value_, it's a declaration.

Answer (score 0):

> If `int *(&ref2)` is the value of `ref2` variable, shouldn't it have the same address of the num_1?

The declaration `int *(&ref2) = p;` defines `ref2` to be a [reference](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references) to `p`.

Part of your misunderstanding may come from wrong output you get from using inappropriate `printf` conversion specifiers; it's wrong to print addresses with `%d` - in your first and third `printf` use `%p` instead. It might become clearer if you add

```
    printf("p : %p\n", p);
```

Comment: I hadn't understood the reference variables exactly when I asked that question. Thank you for answering me!! and have a good day